# Generate all unique pairs of factor and align other variables in same way R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a data frame with unique personal IDs and measurements for each individual, e.g.

```
> personDat <- data.frame(personID = c("A","B","C","D"),value = rnorm(4))
> personDat
  personID      value
1        A -0.9246883
2        B  0.5175514
3        C -1.0109688
4        D  1.1614124
```

Now I need to create all unique pairs of individuals, which I can do with the `combn` function:

```
> perCombs <- t(combn(personDat$personID,2))
> perCombs
     [,1] [,2]
[1,] A    B   
[2,] A    C   
[3,] A    D   
[4,] B    C   
[5,] B    D   
[6,] C    D   
Levels: A B C D
```

Now I would like to add two extra columns to `perCombs`, one for the corresponding measurement/value from the second column in `personDat` for the first personID and then the corresponding value for the second personID.

Basically I need to do a binary operation on the all values of unique pairs of personID, and if I have the columns I can do it in a fast vectorised manner.

**EDIT:** The naive way to do this would be:

```
perCombs <- data.frame(per1 = perCombs[,1],
                       per2 = perCombs[,2],
                       val1 = matrix(0,6,1),
                       val2 = matrix(0,6,1))
for(i in 1:6){
  print(i)
  perCombs[i,3] <- personDat[as.character(personDat$personID)==as.character(perCombs[i,1]),2]
  perCombs[i,4] <- personDat[as.character(personDat$personID)==as.character(perCombs[i,2]),2]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
cbind(perCombs,  `dim<-`(personDat$value[match(perCombs, 
                         personDat$personID)], dim(perCombs)))
```

Comment: @Gumeo Make sure that you use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data.frame` so as to avoid converting to `factor`

Comment: Noted! That is convenient! Thanks!